# How to make to border-bottom line longer with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

1. I would like to extend the border-bottom line longer than ever as the image below:

If this is impossible and you have any suggestion to make a change into my code, that would be great.

[image: border-bottom length]

**HTML:**

```
<table id="showRoom">
<tr class="box_shadow">
    <td class="text_plant_address"> <span class="text_plant">Plant 1</span>

        <br /> <span class="text_address">Street 2, Dong An Industrial Park</span>

    </td>
</tr>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
        background-color: #F6F6F6;
    }

    #showRoom {
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: auto;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

    table .box_shadow {
        background-color: #FFF;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
        display: block;
        -webkit-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
        box-shadow: -4px 4px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.2);
    }

    table tr .text_plant_address {
        background-color: #FFF;
        width: 175px;
        height: 175px;
        font-size: 18px;
        line-height: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: 'Scada', sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    table tr td span {
        height: 87.5px;
        width: auto;
    }

    table tr td .text_plant {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    }

    table tr td .text_address {
        font-size: 10px;
    }
```

Here is my **JSFIDDLE**: **http://jsfiddle.net/QTNr5/**

2.Does anyone know the name of the font below?

[image: Font name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add Padding

```
table tr td .text_plant {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    padding: 0 20px; /* or how longer you want */
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aash1010/QTNr5/3/)**

**For the font -**

1) If you have a just image file than just keep on trying random fonts the only this is solution i guess.

2) If its on some web page inspect it via firebug or any other code inspection tool.

3) If its psd or vector open it in its respective tool and try editing the font software will tell you the name like Photoshop etc.

4) Try this http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/ for getting font name from a JPG image.

I hope any of these will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your code. That works very well! It's OK if you don't know the question 2.

Comment: @PMay1903 i have updated the answer for the second part of your question.

Comment: **@GCyrillus**: I am looking for the way to make the line longer than itself. **Aamir Shahzad** did it very well.

Comment: @PMay1903 no problem, it is your screen shot that confused me, i did not believe it was such a simple matter as padding on each sides to only grow width of this container:)

Comment: **@GCyrillus**: Yup, it was also very hard to me to explain to you. However, I've got the answer in both extending the line and making it red as an image above.

Comment: try this http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/   it may help you in  getting the font name

Comment: @N.Nihar can i add your comment in my answer?

Comment: @ Aamir Shahzad go ahead dude

Answer (score 1):

You can move the border bottom from the text_plant and make it a border top on text_address like so: http://jsfiddle.net/QTNr5/2/

```
table tr td .text_plant {

}
table tr td .text_address {
    font-size: 10px;
    border-top: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    padding-top: 4px;
}
```

Or if you want it shorter you can add padding let and right to your text_plant like this: http://jsfiddle.net/QTNr5/4/

```
table tr td .text_plant {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
    padding:0 20px;
}
```

Comment: Those methods are awesome. I've got 2 ways to solve the problem. Thank you very much! How about question 2? it's OK if you don't know that.

Answer (score 1):

`<edit>` question misunderstood, answer gives a bottom border that is red, white and red again :) red on the outer parts ....[image: 3colors bottom border] `</edit>`

---

You can use pseudo element to draw the red part :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/axvgl/

```
td {
  text-align:center;
}
.text_plant {
  font-size:2em;
  border-bottom:solid white;
  box-shadow:
    0 1px 0 gray, 
    inset 0 -1px 0 lightgray;
}
.text_plant:before,
.text_plant:after {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:1.25em;
  box-shadow:inherit;
  border-bottom:solid red;
  margin-bottom:-3px;/* size of border*/
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

---

Or use gradient http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ftmDn/

```
td {
  text-align:center;
}
.text_plant {
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:2em;
  padding:0 1em;
  box-shadow:
    0 1px 0 gray;

  background:linear-gradient(to left, red 20%,white 20%,white 80%,red 80%) bottom no-repeat, linear-gradient(gray,gray) no-repeat bottom;
  background-size:100% 3px, 100% 4px ;
}
```

Comment: That's awesome. Luckily, what you have done is the next step that I need to work. lol

Comment: oki, so you made 3 question with only one answer possible when I and MarioD fully answered to them ?  padding itself doesn't easily draw the red part on the outer side of text unless padding and gradient match same values :)

Comment: You're all right :-) I would love to rate your comment but there is only one answer is the first one correct and also is the best one. Hence, if I have a problem with that in the next time, I will vote for you :-)

Answer (score 1):

if you want your solution in any how..
then i will recommend this..

Use 3   before plant 1 and 3   after that.. 
like this

```
<td class="text_plant_address"> <span class="text_plant">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Plant 1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
```

i know its not best answer but hope it will help and you can increase   according to u

Comment: oops in my line (&nbsp;) are not showing..but i gave you example.i hope that will help..:)

Comment: That is a cheating way. However, it's wise and I like it! :-)

Comment: heheh sorry but m a beginner and i learn one thing that just get your solution and its not cheating at all..its just very simple answer :) and my first answer too..so m happy happy :)

Answer (score 1):

You could change your spans to divs and remove the br. Divs will display as blocks by default,  so they take up the full width of the td. I modified your fiddle to show the divs. If you don't want it to touch the edges of the box, add padding to your td.

http://jsfiddle.net/mrNXW/

```
<td>
  <div class="plant">Plant 1</div>
  <div class="address">Street 2, Dong An Industrial Park</div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The font you're looking for I believe is this:

http://www.dafont.com/ballpark-weiner.font

Comment: you got half of the question http://www.dafont.com/ballpark-weiner.font?text=Fimtung or a third of it ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, try adding: `padding: 10px 0` to the `<span>`.

Comment: Thank you. According to your code, this might affect both two `<span>` tags. Should I need to put an "id" attribute to the span to make it specific? Here is the updated **JSFIDDLE**: **http://jsfiddle.net/QTNr5/1/**